# Unable to update endpoint with invalid token

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update the fixture with a new one assigned to the logged in user. I am getting a `401 error. the token is invalid`

What am I doing wrong?

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  let fixture = new Fixture({
    home_team: req.body.home_team,
    away_team: req.body.away_team,
    date: req.body.date,
    time: req.body.time,
    venue: req.body.venue,
    home_team_logo: req.body.home_team_logo,
    away_team_logo: req.body.away_team_logo,
  });
  fixture = await fixture.save();
  if (!fixture) {
    return res.status(404).send("the fixture cannot be created!");
  } else {
    console.log("fixture created", res);
    res.send(fixture);
  }
});
```